# Make a list of up servers and pass that list to work with my actual playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have an ansible playbook as shown below and it works fine most of the times. But recently what I am noticing is it is getting stuck on some of the servers from `ALL` group and just sits there. It doesn't even move forward to other servers in the `ALL` list.

```
# This will copy files
---
- hosts: ALL
  serial: "{{ num_serial }}"
  tasks:
      - name: copy files
        shell: "(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com 'ls -1 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/copy/stuff/*' | parallel -j20 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com:{} /data/records/')"

      - name: sleep for 5 sec
        pause: seconds=5
```

So when I started debugging, I noticed on the actual server it is getting stuck - I can ssh (login) fine but when I run `ps` command then it just hangs and I don't get my cursor back so that means ansible is also getting stuck executing above scp command on that server.

So my question is even if I have some server in that state, why not just Ansible times out and move to other server? IS there anything we can do here so that ansible doesnt pause everything just waiting for that server to respond.

Note server is up and running and I can ssh fine but when we run `ps` command it just hangs and because of that ansible is also hanging.

Is there any way to run this command `ps aux | grep app` on all the servers in `ALL` group and make a list of all the servers which executed this command fine (and if gets hang on some server then time out and move to other server in ALL list) and then pass on that list to work with my above ansible playbook? Can we do all this in one playbook?

**Update:-**

I am getting an error like this:

```
ERROR! The 'pause' module bypasses the host loop, which is currently not supported in the free strategy and would instead execute for every host in the inventory list.

The error appears to have been in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/process/check.yml': line 10, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


      - name: sleep for 5 sec
        ^ here
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 1):

*`(Ansible is getting stuck executing scp command on that server). If I have some server in that state, why not just Ansible times out and move to other servers?`*

Very probably the plays run with [linear strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#strategies)

> By default, plays run with a linear strategy, in which **all hosts will run each task before any host starts the next task**

Use [free strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#strategies)

> which allows **each host to run until the end of the play as fast as it can**

```
- hosts: all
  serial: "{{ num_serial }}"
  strategy: free
  tasks:
```

To try [async](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling) the playbook below with 3 hosts in the group 'test' asynchronously let the hosts sleep random number (1-10) of seconds and wait 5 seconds for the hosts to finish. Then retries once to collect the *async_status* and exit the play. Next play at *localhost* will run when at least one host succeeds and will print the status of each host.

```
- hosts: test
  strategy: free
  vars:
    max_sleep_time: 10
    max_wait_time: 5
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_time: "{{ max_sleep_time|random(start=1) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Sleep {{ my_time }} seconds"
    - command: "sleep {{ my_time }}"
      register: play_status
      async: "{{ max_wait_time }}"
      poll: 0
    - async_status:
        jid: "{{ play_status.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: play_status
      until: play_status.finished
      retries: 1

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} finished: {{ hostvars[item].play_status.finished }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['test'] }}"
```

The output (abridged) shows hosts test_01 and test_03 slept 9 seconds, did not finish in time (max_wait_time: 5) and failed.

```
TASK [debug]
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "Sleep 9 seconds"
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": "Sleep 1 seconds"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "msg": "Sleep 9 seconds"
}
TASK [async_status]
changed: [test_02]
fatal: [test_01]: FAILED! => {"ansible_job_id": "10701665445.1564", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 0, "started": 1}
fatal: [test_03]: FAILED! => {"ansible_job_id": "752000555573.1558", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 0, "started": 1}
...
TASK [debug]
ok: [localhost] => (item=test_01) => {
    "msg": "test_01 finished: 0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=test_02) => {
    "msg": "test_02 finished: 1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=test_03) => {
    "msg": "test_03 finished: 0"
}
...
PLAY RECAP
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_01                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1   
test_02                    : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Set `max_wait_time > max_sleep_time` to see all hosts finished.

Comment: I am getting this error when I run with free strategy - `ERROR! The 'pause' module bypasses the host loop, which is currently not supported in the free strategy and would instead execute for every host in the inventory list.`. I updated my question with full error message as well. So in short I want to run that particular task on x number of machines in parallel and then sleep for some time and then do the same thing. I am not sure whether this is possible.

Comment: The error is weird. It would take to review the source to understand it, I think. It might be worth to try [async](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling) instead, or synchronise outside the playbook. See [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner).

Comment: Do you think you can provide an example on how to use these with my example? That would help me understand better.

Comment: Sure. I've updated the answer. Feel free to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You could gather facts.

```
---
hosts: all
gather_facts: True
tasks:
```

By gathering facts explicitly, you force Ansible to try to connect to every host (and update your fact cache). If a host is unreachable, it will be skipped for the rest of the playbook. By default the timeout for gathering facts is [10 seconds](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html), so this should reduce the amount of time you have to wait.